# How to fetch more than 50 Jira issues?

Tags: java, api, jira

I'm trying to get all the tasks from Jirà using the API.
I found the [working code](https://pastebin.com/WUMZ0vZa):

```
public class CustomJiraRestClient {

    private static final String JIRA_URL = "http://jira-dev:8080";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "admin";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Construct the JRJC client
        System.out.println(String.format("Logging in to %s with username '%s' and password '%s'", JIRA_URL, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD));
        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
        JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

        // Invoke the JRJC Client
        Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("admin");
        User user = promise.claim();

        Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project = MYPURRJECT AND status in (Closed, Completed, Resolved) ORDER BY assignee, resolutiondate");

        for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromise.claim().getIssues()) {
            System.out.println(issue.getSummary());
        }

        // Done
        System.out.println("Example complete. Now exiting.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

but there is one problem:
- only the first 50 entries are displayed.
As in the usual, graphical interface - a page with 50 entries on it.
Please help me, how do I get or all the records at once? Or how can I specify the desired page or item.

I found methods:

- `searchResult.getMaxResults();` - the number of all records (n)
- `searchResult.getTotal();` number of entries per page (50)
- `searchResult.getStartIndex();` - the number of the first element (0)

but I can not put them anywhere for use. I can recognize them, but it does not make any sense.

Here are the software versions I use:

- Jira Version: 7.2.13
- atlassian-image-consumer (com.atlassian.image:atlassian-image-consumer:1.0.1:jar)
- carol (carol:carol:1.5.2:jar)
- carol-properties (carol:carol-properties:1.5.2:jar)
- datafile (datafile:datafile:1.3.3:jar)
- hibernate (hibernate:hibernate:2.1.8-atlassian:jar)
- image4j (org.jclarion:image4j:0.7:jar)
- JCaptcha (com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha-api:2.0-alpha-1:jar)
- JCaptcha (com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha:2.0-alpha-1:jar)
- jcommon (jfree:jcommon:1.0.8:jar)
- jfreechart (jfree:jfreechart:1.0.13:jar)
- JSCalendar (1.0)
- jStyleParser (net.sf.cssbox:jstyleparser:1.16-atlassian-1:jar)
- Streaming API for XML (javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2:jar)
- TinyMCE-TinyMCE (4.4.0)
- xapool (xapool:xapool:1.3.1:jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance at the API docs, I would say you need to use the overload [`searchJql(String jql, int maxResults, int startAt)`](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/2.0.0-m2/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/SearchRestClient.html#searchJql(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) and specify the `maxResults` argument.

Comment: I can not understand why, but my method accepts completely different parameters for input:
    Promise <SearchResult> searchJql (\@Nullable String var1, \@Nullable Integer var2, \@Nullable Integer var3, \@Nullable Set <String> var4, \@Nullable Iterable <Expandos> var5);

Comment: Maybe you can find Javadocs as part of the Jira distribution. You could also guess that the Integers in the method signature you posted are the same order as the one I found, and call the method with e.g. `searchJql(query, 500, 0, null, null)`.

Comment: Many thanks. You helped me a lot. I'm ashamed to admit it, but I do not understand it very well.

Answer (score 0):

I use this simply loop for pagination.

```
    List<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<>();
    SearchRestClient searchClient = restClient.getSearchClient();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("*all");  /* you can use simply null set if you dont need all values  */
    int start = 0;
    int maxPerPage = 25;  /* batch size (max 50) */
    int total = 0;
    do {
        SearchResult result = searchClient.searchJql(JQL, maxPerPage, start, set)
                .claim();
        total = result.getTotal();
        start += maxPerPage;
        result.getIssues().iterator().forEachRemaining(issues::add);
    } while (total > start );
```

All issue now in `issues` list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use following function.

```
public List<Issue> getIssuesList(String query) {

    boolean flag = false;
    int start = 0, end=Constants.MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE, totalResults = 0;
    List<Issue> issueList = new ArrayList<Issue>();
    SearchResult searchResult;
    do {
        Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql(query,end,start, null);

        searchResult = searchJqlPromise.claim();
        if(flag==false) {
            totalResults = searchResult.getTotal();
            flag=true;
        };
        List<Issue> res = (List<Issue>) searchResult.getIssues();
        issueList.addAll(res);
        
        start = start + Constants.MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE;
        totalResults -= Constants.MAX_RESULTS_PER_PAGE;
        
    } while(totalResults>0);
    
    return issueList;

}
```